# Connection reset when I try to download artifacts from Sonatype Nexus with HTTP

Tags: maven, http, nexus, large-files, sonatype

I setup a Sonatype Nexus repository on my own server at home.
The server is setup with HTTP on port 8081, and looks like it works okay from the browser both locally and remotely.

The problem is that when I try to download certain artifacts (only some of them, usually more than 500Kb) the connection systematically closes (on server side) before the transfer is completed, resulting in a network error.

```
curl -H --url http://<myserver>:8081/..../artifact.jar
> ....
> curl: (18) transfer closed with 116756 bytes remaining to read
```

The problem magically disappears when I setup nexus to run with ssl (on https, port 8443), but that requires me to verify the certificate with verisign or such, which just complicates the matter.

Why does the transfer of the above artifact (approv. 700Kb in total) always fail like that?
What could the causes be?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?  I too am encountering the same problem downloading large files from Nexus.

Comment: Could never solve it or find a reason... I am currently using https as a workaround instead of http.